# Expanding Div to Ful Width

Tags: html, css

I know there are numerous threads on this subject but I couldn't get any of the suggestions I found to work for me. Whether that's due to novice status or because the code wasn't suitable, I don't know. But I'm now pulling my hair our after trying to get the grey background behind the h2 tag "Attachments" and the two lines that follow it to expand to full width, removing the white spaces that are currently to the left and right of this div.

http://bit.ly/1OVprsc

Comment: I'm using Firefox 44.0.2 and cannot confirm that there are white spaces  on the left side or on the right side. From my view, it is full width relative to text.

Comment: Try show us a picture of what you see.. because for me too seems ok ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use negative margins and padding to extend the background in both directions.

```
margin: 0 -9999rem;
padding: 0.25rem 9999rem;
```

Comment: Tried this, and the background did expand, but not the text has all gone to left sized and stacked (see;http://bit.ly/1OVprsc).Do you know how to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: remove the width:100% you don't need that

Comment: @CCHert I see that you fixed that

Comment: Thanks a lot. Should this hold up over any screen res/browser?

Comment: yes, here's a bonus:
http://design.google.com/resizer/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reviewminr.com%2Fproduct-reviews%2Fcarpet-cleaner-reviews%2Fbissell-spotclean-pro-3624-review%23attachments

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your grey div is inside g-container div which have width that is not full one. So if you want to have that grey div full width u must change your structure into something like this:

```
<div class="g-container">
CONTENT
</div>
<div class="grey-div"></div>
<div class="g-container">
CONTENT
</div>
```

Or you can do it with position absolute but then none of the parent of the grey div shouldn`t be position relative so the grey div can be absolute relative to body.